# Generate 3D surface with C# console application via DLL?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I already have a 3D surface plot in C# WPF Application and I have all my code in C# console application.

Is it possible to save the WPF Application as a DLL and use it for my console application, so that when I run my console application, the 3D surface is generated automatically at the end of the program (taking into account the updates in the 3D surface) ?

If not, any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: Actually I don't know if it is possible to save the WPF application as a DLL, and if it is do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the compiler/build settings to switch from Windows Application to Class Library and provide a public type/interface to execute the logic in the DLL. Solution | Properties | Application tab.

Or you could change the the WPF application by adding a socket, named pipe or other inter process communication mechanism and send information from the console application to the WPF Application.